# How is the UDP server example safe?

Tags: rust, thread-safety

I have a UDP server example, which is working:

```
let mut socket = UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:12345")?;
let mut buf = [0; 4096];
loop {
    let sock = socket.try_clone()?;
    match socket.recv_from(&mut buf) {
        Ok((amt, src)) => {
            thread::spawn(move || {
                println!("Handling connection from {}", &src);
                let buf = &mut buf[..amt];
                buf.reverse();
                sock.send_to(&buf, &src).expect("error sending");
            });
        },
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("Err: {}", err);
        }
    }
}
```

It *looks* like all incoming UDP packets are sharing the same buffer.

If two UDP packets arrive at the same time, won't the second packet overwrite the first in `buf`, leading to the second packet's (reversed) content being sent back to **both** senders?

How does Rust prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the buffer is not shared among threads but implicitly copied before starting a new one. From the [array doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html):

> Arrays of any size are Copy if the element type is Copy

Therefore a **move** keyword forces a buffer movement, which leads to a copy since the same buffer can be used at the next iteration of the loop.